# How can I merge blobs / contours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I use `findContours` for blob detection. Now I would merge close and similar blobs together.

Here are some sample images:

[image] [image] [image]

Is that possible with normal Opencv?

Comment: Better if you add an image. Upload in imageshack.us and give link here. Also specify what do you mean by similar. Is it similar in shape? Or having similar area? etc

Comment: ok i would like merge similar shape that are next to each other. Here are three examples (mark as yellow) thanks for help!

[Image 1](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/2152/image1xg.png)
[Image 2](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/2149/image2kl.png)
[Image 3](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/1000/image3jg.png)

Comment: and those binary images are all after a morphology open - close operation.

Comment: so, basically you are finding the distance between each blobs and merge it if the distance, d is less than 25?

Comment: but there is still a problem, how to handle the new merged blobs? because maybe if one merge two, a third one should be merged too....

Comment: what I can think of is you may want to dilate the merge blobs and then do CCL again.

Answer (score 3):

The input images you gave us are pretty easy to work with:

[image] [image] [image]

The first step is **isolate the yellow blobs from everything else** and a simple color segmentation technique can accomplish this task. You can take a look at [Segmentation & Object Detection by color](http://blog.damiles.com/2010/01/segmentation-object-detection-by-color/) or [Tracking colored objects in OpenCV](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/) to have an idea on how to do it.

[image] [image] [image]

Then, it's time to merge the blobs. One technique in particular that can be useful is the [bounding box](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/), to **put all the blobs inside a rectangle**. Notice in the images below, that there is a green rectangle surrounding the blobs:

[image] [image] [image]

After that, all you need to do is **fill the rectangle with the color of your choice**, thus connecting all the blobs. I'm leaving this last as homework for you.

This is the quickest and most simple approach I could think of. The following code demonstrates how to achieve what I just described:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    if (!img.data)
    {
        std::cout "!!! Failed to open file: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Convert RGB Mat into HSV color space
    cv::Mat hsv;
    cv::cvtColor(img, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    // Split HSV Mat into HSV components
    std::vector<cv::Mat> v;
    cv::split(hsv,v);

    // Erase pixels with low saturation
    int min_sat = 70;
    cv::threshold(v[1], v[1], min_sat, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    /* Work with the saturated image from now on */

// Erode could provide some enhancement, but I'm not sure.
//  cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));
//  cv::erode(v[1], v[1], element);

    // Store the set of points in the image before assembling the bounding box
    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = v[1].begin<uchar>();
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = v[1].end<uchar>();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (*it) points.push_back(it.pos());
    }

    // Compute minimal bounding box
    cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

    // Display bounding box on the original image
    cv::Point2f vertices[4];
    box.points(vertices);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
            cv::line(img, vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % 4], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, CV_AA);
    }

    cv::imshow("box", img);
    //cv::imwrite(argv[2], img);

    cvWaitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer... but you misunderstood me a bit. The yellow blobs aren't really yellow. I just colored them to show you witch blobs i would try to merge. so i'm not able to use color segmentation for isolate the other blobs. Also information like area won't work because maybe there are some other bigger blobs witch i dont like to merge...

Comment: Bah! =\ will think about something else later.

Comment: no, im interested just in that blobs that maybe could be an traffic sing from there size/ratio/area on.

Comment: You must provide as much details as possible in your question, else we will be shooting in the dark. This is a complex problem! You might not get any answers if you don't share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Let me put it this way: from the images you gave us, how do you know which blob is a traffic sign? In my mind, sounds logical that they are the biggest blobs in those images. Am I wrong?

Comment: im sorry if I confuse you. The Problem is maybe there could be a noise Blob that is bigger (maybe a part of the sky when its a blue sign), or there could be also more traffic signs in one image. What i could do is to isolate the very small blobs and very biggest. But then my question is: Sometimes the traffic sign is split in two pieces, now i would like to merge those to one...

Answer (score 2):

i think i did it, thanks to your program details i found this solution: (comments are welcome)

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<vector<Point> > tmp_contours;
    findContours(detectedImg, tmp_contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    vector<vector<Point> >::iterator it1;
    it1 = tmp_contours.begin();

    Mat test;
    test = Mat(FImage.size(), CV_32FC3);

    while (it1 != tmp_contours.end()) {
        vector<Point> approx1;
        approxPolyDP(Mat(*it1), approx1, 3, true);
        Rect box1 = boundingRect(approx1);
        float area1 = contourArea(approx1);



        if ((area1 > 50) && (area1 < 13000) && (box1.width < 100) && (box1.height < 120)) {

            vector<vector<Point> >::iterator it2;
            it2 = tmp_contours.begin();

            while (it2 != tmp_contours.end()) {
                vector<Point> approx2;
                approxPolyDP(Mat(*it2), approx2, 3, true);

                Moments m1 = moments(Mat(approx1), false);
                Moments m2 = moments(Mat(approx2), false);
                float x1 = m1.m10 / m1.m00;
                float y1 = m1.m01 / m1.m00;
                float x2 = m2.m10 / m2.m00;
                float y2 = m2.m01 / m2.m00;

                vector<Point> dist;
                dist.push_back(Point(x1, y1));
                dist.push_back(Point(x2, y2));
                float d = arcLength(dist, false);

                Rect box2 = boundingRect(approx2);
                if (box1 != box2) {

                    if (d < 25) {
                        //Method to merge the vectors
                        approx1 = mergePoints(approx1, approx2);
                    }

                }
                ++it2;

            }
            Rect b = boundingRect(approx1);
            rectangle(test, b, CV_RGB(125, 255, 0), 2);
            contours.push_back(approx1);
        }
        ++it1;
    }
```